# Why does Performance Counter for System Uptime need 2 calls to NextValue?

Tags: performancecounter, perfmon

This is how you obtain the Performance Counter for System Uptime:

```
public TimeSpan GetSystemUptime(){
   PerformanceCounter upTime = new PerformanceCounter("System", "System Up Time");
   upTime.NextValue();
   return TimeSpan.FromSeconds(upTime.NextValue());
}
```

NextValue has to be called twice, because it is 0 on the first call.
But I don't understand WHY it is using a Counter that has to be read twice.
I understand that something like CPU Usage [new PerformanceCounter("Processor Information", "% Processor Time", "_Total")] would Need 2 values, because it is calculating an average over time.
but why would you Need to measure 2 times, when calculating System Uptime?
Wouldn't you just have to measure the current time and compare it with the booting time?

Comment: I agree that the .NextValue() function should default to ignoring the first result.